# Update Object-Element in Array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mean-stack

I´ve read a couple of other posts here on Stackoverflow but havent found any 'general' answer.

Lets say I have a **Structure** like this:

```
{
    personsName: "Bob",
    children: [
       {childsName: "Alice", age: "9", weight: "40"}
       {childsName: "Peter", age: "12", weight: "80"} 
    ]
}
```

Now I want to **edit Peters weight** because it is actually "45"

**I tried:**

```
  .update(
     { personsName: "Bob", children.childsName: "Peter"},
     {
       $set: {children: {weight :"45" } }
     }
   )
```

For me this should be working...Update the childrens weight to "45" for all children that are named "Peter" and belong to "Bob"...
I saw some solutions where they update the array by index, but lets assume we dont know the index, we want to update by the childs property "childsName".

**Whats the general way of doing that?**

Comment: see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Comment: This looks great, but unfortunately I still use an older version and I dont want to change that in my MEAN-Project. There has to be an option for that on the current version too...

Comment: If there was, the ticket was not created at the first place. See my answer, if you are happy with limitations of the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that Bob has no more than 1 Peter, you can use [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) as following:

```
.update(
  { personsName: "Bob", "children.childsName": "Peter"},
  {
    $set: {"children.$.weight" :"45" } 
  }
)
```

Please note that the operator updates the first matching subdocument only, and only as deep as 1 level.

Comment: That was easy - thanks alot!!...seems like I have to do some reading on '$'